# C#: How would you make it so D0 to D9 are converted in numeric form without the D?

Tags: c#

example: (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0) && (e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9)

I'm trying to detect on a keydown event in a textbox that if a numeric key is pressed

(e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0) && (e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9), to display the e.KeyCode as a string into a listbox.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they are defined sequentially in the `enum`:

```
(int)key - (int)Keys.D0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [KeysConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter.aspx) TypeConverter.